# Will I get the same student benefits and discounts in the U.S. as a foreign student?

Tags: usa, education, financial

Am an expat student in the U.S., Am I going to get the same student benefits and discounts in the U.S. just like the local students using my student ID?

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately it is up to the individual company or venue to set whether or not they make a distinction between domestic or international students but I am yet to find one that does.

From [Carnegie Hall](http://www.carnegiehall.org/Students/):

> Buy your tickets at the Box Office on 57th Street and Seventh Avenue. A student photo ID is required for purchase of up to two tickets.

which means that as long as your student ID is valid you should be able to obtain a discounted ticket.

In addition I would think that making a discount/service limited based whether the student has residency in the US or not is likely to bring a constitutional challenge to such limitation but **IANAL**.

Comment: iANAL? sounds like another product from Apple.

Comment: Not quite but that's a different discussion. :)

Comment: +1 in that no establishment is *required* to recognize a particular student ID— even one from a U.S. institution. I had a restaurant in Syracuse, NY try to decline a 10% "student discount" to me once, saying it was a promotion intended only for students enrolled in the local area, whereas I was visiting from about an hour away in Ithaca. (That said, they didn't resist when I insisted).

Comment: @choster That was probably more of a question which school did you have an id from.  I remember being limited for the number of purchases in West Lafayette just because my credit card had an Indiana University logo and colors. :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get around the problem is to get an International Student ID card. You have a lot of information in: http://www.isic.org/
They also connect you to sites that offer discounts. Quite useful.

Comment: I am not sure this will be accepted as a Student ID or help with the concern that discount may be available for the international student.

Comment: This isn't a universal way to get around the problem at all. The ISIC card is issued by a private company; no business or government in the U.S. is required to accept it. All it provides is reassurance for certain organizations which have stated that they *do* accept it.

Comment: I agree that it is not a universal solution, but in my personal experience the ISIC card has been accepted when my normal student ID hasn't.

Comment: if you cannot get a local student ID this might be your best bet.

Comment: @SztupY If you are a student why wouldn't you be able to get School Student ID?

Comment: @Karlson: for example if you are an Erasmus student spending a few semesters abroad in another university it's not self explanatory that you will get a student ID in the guest university, while your native university's student ID might not be accepted abroad.

Comment: @SztupY Erasmus seems to be a Europe only program.  The question was specific to the US.  Where if you are a student you can get an ID from school.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience in a state accredited private University, as a foreign student I was not eligible for any financial aid or (of course) discount on tuition. Anything that required a student ID though is the same for everybody in my experience: foreign students are issued the same Student IDs as everybody else.